# Need to delete a blank space after a tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a design where the strong tag is meant to send whatever comes next to the next line. The CSS looks like this:

```
strong { display: block; }
```

The html is something like this:

```
<p><strong>foo</strong> bar.<p>
```

The problem: The blank space between the strong tag and the text that follows shows up in the next line as an unintended indent. I'm thinking, there's a way to delete the blank space right after the strong tag with jQuery. How can I do that?

Note: I can't reproduce this problem with a Fiddle, so I can't tell if it's actually the space that's causing the indent.

Comment: did you try playing around with `white-space-collapse` property?

Comment: I would need the property just to collapse the first white space after the strong tag, not the spaces that follow. Example, in <p><strong>foo</strong> Something here and here</p> I would only need to collapse the first space. That's why I think jQuery is the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have a fiddle of your problem, I'll toss this out...

IE has a quirk, at least in quirks mode, where white space between elements is rendered.  The solution is to break up the HTML in such a way to keep white space out of the markup..

An example...

```
<a
href="linkk1">This is my test</a><a
href="linkk2">Another</a><a
href="linkk3">Yet another</a>
```

See if that helps.

Comment: Thank you, but I am unable to edit the content already posted, just manipulate it in the front end.

Comment: But you *can* do a 'save as' on the page, edit it by hand to see if this solves the white space issue. If it does, then text nodes can be identified and removed.  Finding the real cause of the problem is the first step towards solving it.

Comment: Ok, I found out the space is not causing the indent. I solved the problem using the jQuery .replaceWith() method for each code that presents itself that way, which is not the ideal solution. It would still be nice to see if someone can find it possible to trim a targeted blank space. If not jQuery, can it be done with php?

Comment: You only told us that you solved the problem.  You didn't say what the problem *was*!  We have no way of knowing what may or may not help at this point.

Comment: Aside from the problem, the actual question is, can I trim a white space right after a tag? The problem is an example, but the question remains the same.

Comment: Find where the whitespace is coming from and fix that.  Anything else runs the risk of having unwanted side effects.  If not now, later.